# Data fetched from database is being displayed incorrectly

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

my db:

[image: link]

data on the site:

[image: link]

code:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","organisation");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM deletebs") or die(mysql_error());;
echo '<pre>'; print_r($result); echo '</pre>';

echo "<!doctype html>
<html lang=\"en\">
  <head>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css\">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>id</th>
<th>below_whom</th>
<th>name</th>
</tr>";
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
echo '<pre>'; print_r($row); echo '</pre>';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['below_whom'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

My question is why the first row is being omitted? I am a little weak on the dbms side. But I believe the query written is correct because some data is being fetched correctly, Why is the data omitted when below_whom is left blank. While creating db, I have made sure that all columns accept null values. Here's the structure of my db.

[image: link]

Comment: mysql_error belongs to a different API, and a different era

Comment: Don't fetch the result twice

Comment: I used mysql_error to find if there were some error in the table. Removing it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: What @Strawberry probably meant was that you are using `mysqli_*` functions mixed with that `mysql_error`, which are two different things. You want [mysqli_error](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly don't remove this `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);` line because you are fetching it twice.

Then instead of doing this:

```html
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { echo "
<tr>"; echo "
  <td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>"; echo "
  <td>" . $row['below_whom'] . "</td>"; echo "
  <td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>"; echo "</tr>"; }
```

try this

```html
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){  
   $id         => $row['id'],
                 $below_whom => $row['below_whom'],
                 $name       => $row['name']
     }
```

now that you have got your data in these variables you can use it anywhere in your code